# Python Dataframes: Count how many of occurrences of value on specific date and delete based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using python and pandas for my assignment. my Datafrmae looks something like this:

| Date | Time | Business hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/4/26 | 0800 | NO |
| 2021/4/26 | 0900 | Yes |
| 2021/4/26 | 1000 | Yes |

I want to figure out if the date was a holiday by counting how many yes and no there are on a specific date - if the count of yes is less then 7, then I would deem that date a Holiday and exclude it from my calculations by deleting it.

I was thinking of adding a holiday column with boolean value. Been looking all over for a solution online but falling short. Im pretty new to Python so i apologise if i said anything stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use transform here with groupby:

```py
s = df["Business hours"].eq("Yes").groupby(df["Date"]).transform("Sum")
df[s >= 7]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Im just having an issue with the code. I still want to keep the dates and times where business hours == no. Just want to remove the business hours that are essentially holidays. Could you point me in the direction of getting that to work?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688899/pandas-checking-if-a-date-is-a-holiday-and-assigning-boolean-value)

Comment: my holidays are not calender ones, they are dependent on how many 'yes' in a day

Comment: I figured it out. Thought I would share how i did it incase anyone else needs it. I made a condition in a variable 'b = df[(s < 14) & (df['Bussiness Hours'] == 'Yes')].index' then just droped the rows so 'df.drop(b, inplace=True )'

Answer (score 1):

Try groupby filter function :

```
def filter_rows(x):
    try:
        x['Business hours'].value_counts()['Yes'] >= 7
        return True
    except KeyError as e:
        return False
df = df.groupby('Date').filter(filter_rows)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but i keep getting 'Keyword error: 'Yes'

Comment: @elzzup that's probably some groups contains only 'No'. I've updated the filter function